# Machine doesn't recognize some USB flash drives

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, usb-flash-drive

My friend's Windows 7 x64 ultimate machine recognizes some USB flash drives but not some other ones. The types of all are USB2 and also all drivers are installed (device manager). I don't know what is the problem. 
I also have done the works of here:
http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/my-machine-doesnt-recognize-some-usb-flash-drives.202702/#post-1404832

And this is an image from that flash drive (silicon-Power 4g).
Any idea how to solve he problem please?

[image]

Comment: Will this problem be solved if I re-install the Windows, this time Win 7 x86?

Comment: What's the error displayed in the device properties?

Comment: This is the message: _The drivers for this device are not installed. (Code 28). Access is denied._